# Make the Ignore theme more suitable for spoilers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, design, spoilers

When I spot a tag about a movie / show I plan to watch, I ignore it to help hide the spoilers, unfortunately the only slight reduction in colour doesn't really help and I inadvertently find myself reading the first few words of the question before my brain catches on and I skip down.

As spoilers are far more annoying than just occasionally seeing topics about programming languages you don't know (for example), would it be possible to either alter the Ignore theme to make the questions unreadable without direct interaction:

> Like this

Or add another 'Spoilers' option to the 'Favourite / Ignore / Do Nothing' system in place for tags already?

Comment: Given that the first few words of a question title *shouldn't* spoil anything at all, I have a hard time seeing this as an actual problem. Please don't hide those questions, I still want to see them.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Why are you ignoring tags that you want to see?

Comment: Because I care about seeing every possible question and not get stuff just completely hidden from me, while still getting potentially uninteresting stuff clearly marked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you already can actually configure your ignored questions to not only show greyed out but be completely hidden. Just visit your profile, click the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab, select the ["Preferences" page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/9682) and down at the bottom, where you can configure your ignored tags, check the box that says *"Hide questions in your ignored tags"*.

This of course has the disadvantage that you then don't ever get to see any question that has one of your ignored tags and thus might miss important questions needing your attention. But this might still be more fitting to your goal of never setting an eye upon a single letter of a question with possibly spoiling contents.

Comment: Just a note that this hides the questions from the front page and the various filtered lists (new, active, featured), but these questions will still show up in your review queue. They'll also show up in the Hot Network List.